# Redis number of connections vs Single Thread

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, redis

I read that Redis is Single Thread.

Using jedis client (java) we can configure pool connections, like as:

```
spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-active=8 # Maximum number of connections that can be allocated by the pool at a given time. Use a negative value for no limit.
spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-idle=8 # Maximum number of "idle" connections in the pool. Use a negative value to indicate an unlimited number of idle connections.
spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-wait=-1ms # Maximum amount of time a connection allocation should block before throwing an exception when the pool is exhausted. Use a negative value to block indefinitely.
spring.redis.jedis.pool.min-idle=0 # Target for the minimum number of idle connections to maintain in the pool. This setting only has an effect if it is positive.
```

I know that pool connection is important to get a connect already opened, therefore not spending time to connect again.

Imagine that 8 "client request" uses all available pools, so 8 connections will be used, these clients do a "GET" command in Redis.

Redis will be process one thread per time? Each thread needs wait for other to finish since Redis is Single Thread? In this case when 1 "GET" it is processing other 7 are in Redis queue?

How *max-active* impacts Redis performance if Redis is Single Thread?

Answer (score 1):

Only main loop of Redis is single thread. It uses [client buffers](https://redislabs.com/blog/top-redis-headaches-for-devops-client-buffers/) in separate threads to speed up processing. Most of the time you spend getting data from Redis is networking time. They help with that. This means unless you are storing really big objects, you will get almost linear throughput increase.

Here I measured different setups for Lettuce (another client). I expect 'pooled' setup to be very similar to what you will get with Jedis: [Redis is single thread. Then why should I use lettuce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409344/redis-is-single-thread-then-why-should-i-use-lettuce/)